# Changing form variables and need to change javascript to new variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am a complete newbie to javascript.  I have some js on my website that is handling hiding some divs in a form.  I'm wanting to change some of the values of the form, and I'm confused by some of the syntax of the javascript.  Here is the html and script that I am working with:

```
<div class="outeremailcontainer">
    <div id="emailcontainer">
        <?php include('verify.php'); ?>
        <form action="../index_success.php" method="post" id="sendEmail" class="email">
            <h3 class="register2">Newsletter Signup:</h3>
            <ul class="forms email">
                <li class="name">
                    <label for="yourName">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="yourName" class="info" id="yourName" value="<?php echo $_POST['yourName']; ?>" /><br />
                </li>
                <li class="city"><label for="yourCity">City: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="yourCity" class="info" id="yourCity" value="<?php echo $_POST['yourCity']; ?>" /><br />
                </li>
                <li class="email">
                    <label for="emailFrom">Email: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="emailFrom" class="info" id="emailFrom" value="<?php echo $_POST['emailFrom']; ?>" />
                     <?php if(isset($emailFromError)) echo '<span class="error">'.$emailFromError.'</span>';
                     ?>
                </li>
                <li class="buttons email">
                     <button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button>
                     <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    <div class="clearing">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#emailFrom')
  .focus(function(){
   if ($('#overlay').length) { return; } // don't keep adding overlays if one exists
 $('#sendEmail')

 .find('.name, .city').slideDown(300, function(){ $(this).show(); });
 $('.outeremailcontainer').css({ position: 'relative', bottom: 0, left: 0, zIndex:       1001 });
 $('<div id="overlay"></div>').appendTo('body');
 });

$('#overlay').live('click', function(){
$('#sendEmail')
 .css({ backgroundColor : 'transparent' })
 .find('.name, .city').slideUp(300);
$('.outeremailcontainer').css({ position : 'static' });
$('#overlay').remove();
 });

});
```

There is also a script at the bottom of the page in an include:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#emailFrom')
.focus(function(){
 if ($('#overlay').length) { return; } // don't keep adding overlays if one exists
 $('#sendEmail')

  .find('.name, .city').slideDown(300, function(){ $(this).show(); });
 $('.outeremailcontainer').css({ position: 'relative', bottom: 0, left: 0, zIndex : 1001 });
 $('<div id="overlay"></div>').appendTo('body');
 });

  $('#overlay').live('click', function(){
 $('#sendEmail')
  .css({ backgroundColor : 'transparent' })
  .find('.name, .city').slideUp(300);
 $('.outeremailcontainer').css({ position : 'static' });
 $('#overlay').remove();
  });

});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(){
    $(".error").hide();
    var hasError = false;
    var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;


    var emailFromVal = $("#emailFrom").val();

    if(emailFromVal == '') {
      $("#emailFrom").after('<span class="error"><br />You forgot to enter the email address to send from.</span>');
      hasError = true;

    } else if(!emailReg.test(emailFromVal)) {
      $("#emailFrom").after('<span class="error"<br />>Enter a valid email address to send from.</span>');
      hasError = true;
}

    var yourNameVal = $("#yourName").val();
    if(yourNameVal == '') {
    $("#yourName").after('<span class="error"><br />You forgot to enter your name.</span>');
    hasError = true;
}

 var yourCityVal = $("#yourCity").val();
if(yourCityVal == '') {
    $("#yourCity").after('<span class="error"><br />You forgot to enter your city.</span>');
    hasError = true;
}
if(hasError == false) {
  $(this).hide();
  $("#sendEmail li.buttons").append('<img src="/wp-content/themes/default/images/template/loading.gif" alt="Loading" id="loading" />');
  $.post("/includes/sendemail.php",
//emailTo: emailToVal, 
       { emailFrom: emailFromVal, yourName: yourNameVal, yourCity: yourCityVal  },
         function(data){
        $("#sendEmail").slideUp("normal", function() {
          $("#sendEmail").before('<h3 class="register2">Thank you!  You\'re on the email list!</h3><p class="emailbox">Click <a href="xxx">HERE</a> for your free song.</p>');
        });
         }
     );
}
return false;
 });
});
```

The above code all works just fine.   However, I am wanting to use a different form action with some different variables.  The form part of the code will need to look like this:

```
    <div class="outeremailcontainer">
    <div id="emailcontainer">
        <?php include('verify.php'); ?>
        <form action="https://madmimi.com/signups/subscribe/66160" method="post" id="mad_mimi_signup_form" class="email">
            <h3 class="register2">Newsletter Signup:</h3>
            <ul class="forms email">
                <li class="name">
                    <label for="signup_name">Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="signup[name]" class="info" id="signup_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['signup_name']; ?>" /><br />
                </li>
                <li class="city"><label for="signup_city">City: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="signup[city]" class="info" id="signup_city" value="<?php echo $_POST['signup_city']; ?>" /><br />
                </li>
                <li class="email">
                    <label for="signup_email">Email: </label>
                    <input type="text" name="signup[email]" class="required" id="signup_email" value="<?php echo $_POST['signup_email']; ?>" />
                     <?php if(isset($emailFromError)) echo '<span class="error">'.$emailFromError.'</span>';
                     ?>
                </li>
                <li class="buttons email">
                     <button type="submit" id="webform_submit_button">Send</button>
                     <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
                </li>
            </ul>
        </form>
    <div class="clearing">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can't figure out which of the js code I will need to change for the div hiding actions to still work with the new values.  Can anyone help with this?  Thanks!

Comment: have you noticed you have duplicate code?

Comment: I did, and what is strange to me is that if I remove the top code, the script no longer works.  I know PHP but not javascript, so I'm hoping to learn more as I go here with this code....

Comment: i am still trying to figure out exactly what it is you are trying to acomplish, what sections of the html do you want to hide?

Comment: Actually-I think you have helped me with the duplicate code comment.  I was changing the js code in the top, but didn't notice the duplicate code, so I think I was overriding those variables.  I just deleted the first js code, and the slide down action is still working.  To answer your question, this is an email signup form and when the user clicks on the email input box, the Name and City input boxes slide down to get that information as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to change the names of the fields in your JS file:

```
<input type="text" name="yourName" class="info" id="yourName" value="<?php echo $_POST['yourName']; ?>" />
```

has turned into:

```
<input type="text" name="signup[name]" class="info" id="signup_name" value="<?php echo $_POST['signup_name']; ?>" />
```

so your JS needs to change from

```
var yourNameVal = $("#yourName").val();
```

to

```
var yourNameVal = $("#signup_name").val();
```

and the same goes for all your fields, you need to select the correct element in order to manipulate it

here is a link expalining [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)